# Haskell: Is there a safe/total version of (!!)?

Tags: haskell

I tried [looking up `Int -> [a] -> Maybe a` on hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20Maybe%20a), but no luck.

I feel like this should be in a standard library somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a library called [Safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safe/latest/doc/html/Safe.html#v%3aatMay) on Hackage which holds a function:

```
atMay :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
```

Comment: there is a library Safe on hackage which holds a function 
`atMay :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a`
(http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safe/latest/doc/html/Safe.html#v:atMay)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - you promote that comment to your answer, and you win.

Comment: Wow this answer was incredibly confusing until I realized the first two comments were in response to the answer before it was edited.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one in the standard library (would be nice, though), but here's one way to implement it (also works for infinite lists):

```
(!!!) :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
[]     !!! _ = Nothing
(x:xs) !!! n
    | n < 0     = Nothing
    | n == 0    = Just x
    | otherwise = xs !!! (n-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible definition for such a function (mostly stolen from the definition of `(!!)`):

```
xs     !!! n | n < 0 =  Nothing
[]     !!! _         =  Nothing
(x:_)  !!! 0         =  Just x
(_:xs) !!! n         =  xs !!! (n-1)
```

Comment: ... I think the `error` statement disqualifies this for totality.

Comment: Yeah, that just occurred to me. I guess I was thinking "total with respect to the list". Of course, it's easily total-fied :).

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
(!!!) :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
xs !!! n = Maybe.listToMaybe $ drop n xs
```